# CRM 2011 call to getAttribute fails

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, crm

As of this morning, we're having issues on our CRM site.  Any calls to `Xrm.Page.getAttribute` fail, regardless of the attribute.  Also, if I debug with IE9, I find that `Xrm.Page` is valid, but checking `Xrm.Page.data` returns null, so any calls to anything after that will always fail (`Xrm.Page.data.entity`, etc.)

Any idea why this is happening?  The error is even being called by CRM and when I go to request to send it to Microsoft, the error in the XML is :

> Object doesn't support property or method 'getAttribute'

Most likely because of the above issues.

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is this on all entities or a specific entity?

Comment: Is this On Premise or Online? The day you asked this question, Online was having some issues. Is this still an issue?

Answer (score 0):

These kind of errors can occur when there is a naming collision between a custom JScript function and a JScript function that is a built-in part of the Dynamics CRM form. Your custom function could simply replace a function the CRM form is depending on.

Remove all custom scripts and check them one by one.

A good practice is to place all of your custom functions in your own namespace. It would typically be declared like this:

```
var MySpace = MySpace || {};
```

Then add your function like this:

```
MySpace.MyFunction = function() {
    alert('Example');
};
```